# Best Guide to Chemical Thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, books

I understand thermodynamics in a physicsy way - at the level of Callen's *Thermodynamics*. However, my chemical thermodynamics is quite rusty: concepts like fugacity and activity coefficients are only vaguely familiar from undergrad courses.

I'm looking for a *well written, rigorous and succinct* guide to advanced chemical thermodynamics - at the level where I can read papers on ENRTL equations of state, or understand Pitzer models fully. If it is geared towards chemical engineers (like myself) that would be a bonus.

Basically, I consider Callen's book a classic, and wonder if there's anything that good within chemical thermodynamics.

Does such a book exist? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest:

1) [Introduction to Chemical Engineering Thermodynamics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071247084) by Smith, Van Ness, and Abbott;

2) [Chemical, Biochemical, and Engineering Thermodynamics](http://books.unbeatablesale.com/chemical_biochemical_engineering_thermodynamics_by_sandler_stanley_i_1152064025.php) by Sandler; and

3) This is more suitable for advanced reading or for a graduate student: [Thermodynamics and Its Applications](http://web.mit.edu/testerel/thermo/) by Tester and Modell.